The use of 'de': with or without definite article?
How do I know when to use 'de' or 'de la/du' in a sentence?
Which of the following examples are correct?

Je mange du pain avec la confiture de fraise / Je mange du pain avec la confiture de la fraise
L'histoire de France / L'histoire de la France
La societé de débat anglais / La société du débat anglais

Je vous remercie d'avance!

Does this answer your question? Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »

✅❓Je mange du pain avec la confiture de fraise (you probably want: '[...] avec de la confiture [...]')
❌ Je mange du pain avec la confiture de la fraise
✅ L'histoire de France (a school subject)
✅ L'histoire de la France  (what the above tells)
❓La société de débat anglais
❓La société du débat anglais

Here is my perspective as a French speaker.
You cannot say "confiture de la fraise" unless you are personally sure that it has been made with one specific single "fraise" (strawberry). So you need to use the generic "confiture de fraises" as it is unlikely that you can make confiture with just one strawberry.
"L'histoire de France" or "de la France" both work. For countries you can skip the "la" but for other topics you would have to include it: "l'histoire de la seconde guerre mondiale", "l'histoire de la géologie". But you would not put the "la" for people: "L'histoire de Napoléon".
For the last one I think we don't say "société de débat" but rather "club de discussion".
"Club de discussion anglais" if the purpose is to discuss/debate about or in English, I'd say.

Hmm, confiture de la fraise would mean the jam was made with a single strawberry or that the jam "belongs" to a strawberry. Both are quite unlikely events...

Welcome to Fr.SE! I'd translate association de débat[s], mostly for pedantic faithfulness to the English: your club de discussion is pretty close in meaning. I'd write club de discussion en anglais. I would write histoire de la France coloniale; can't think of an instance with histoire de la France in the absolute.
